# Enzyme - Mock non-instance variables

Tags: reactjs, sinon, enzyme

I have the following React Component:

```
const titleText = translate('header.about');

const About = ({onClose}) => (
  <div>
    <ModalHeader title={titleText} onClose={onClose} />
    <Content />
  </div>
);
```

I also have a test file that checks the `onClose` functionality, which works fine:

```
const spy = sinon.spy();
const wrapper = shallow(<About onClose={spy} />);  // I also tried "mount()"

...

assert.equal(spy.callCount, 1, 'onClose was called exactly once');
```

However, I get the following warning in the terminal when running the test:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `title` is marked as required in `ModalHeader`, but its value is `undefined`
```

I don't get the warning in the browser, only when running the test. While it's only a warning, I'd rather fix this if possible.

Any way to give a mock value to `title`? I am only interested in possible solutions for mocking local variables (i.e `titleText` in this example).

Comment: Why not accept it as a prop?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to mock such variables.

Comment: I solved this by using `proxyquire` to mock my `translate` library (since I am not using Jest). Otherwise @yusinto's answer would likely be good.

Comment: proxyquire is cool! Glad you solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Using jest, you can mock the translate package like so:

```
// this will mock the translate package
jest.mock('translate', () => () => 'some test title');

const spy = sinon.spy();
const wrapper = shallow(<About onClose={spy} />);

...

assert.equal(spy.callCount, 1, 'onClose was called exactly once');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
const spy = sinon.spy();
const wrapper = shallow(<About title ="test title" onClose={spy} />); 

...

assert.equal(spy.callCount, 1, 'onClose was called exactly once');
```